# Is installing NRPE on an ESXi for monitoring purpose a good idea?

Tags: backup, vmware-esxi, nrpe, ghettovcb

I am using Centreon to monitore our VMs.

I've also VM backups done on the ESXi (5.5.0) with ghettoVCB and sent to a NAS mounted on NFS.

Now I would like to monitore those backups with a home made script that would parse ghettoVCB logs and send the result to my monitoring server. $
So for that I want to install the NRPE daemon on the esxi in order to run that script from my monitoring server once a day.

Is that a good idea, knowing that nrpe is a daemon that would run everytime and consume resources and also security wise?

Any other idea to monitore the backups ?

Thanks!

Comment: Installing anything on esxi is a great way for vmware to refuse to honour your service contract

Comment: Really? You mean we aren't supposed to install anything on an ESXi ? What other option do we have then ?

Comment: ESXi has a SNMP server built in.  You use that.

Comment: Okay thank you. trying to extend snmp to run custom scripts on esxi but there is no conf file snmpd.conf or snmp.conf on the ESXI, even though I enabled the snmp service. How do one configure snmp to run custom scrips on ESXI? That's another thread I guess.

Comment: You're very close to the edge of what's considered acceptable use of ESXi.

Comment: Okay I found a better idea: mount the backup destination in read only on my monitoring server and monitore the results from there. Thanks! ( How do I close this thread? :/)

Comment: I would recommend answering your own question.